# Kafka custom suppress behavior with commit.interval.ms

Tags: apache-kafka, aggregate, apache-kafka-streams

In Kafka streams, if we have multiple partitions and want to aggregate messages based on a key and just produce the final results of the aggregation for the key. We had to use custom suppressor using transforms that punctuate and forward the key based on window duration of 10 secs for each of the key, since we don't have continuous flow of messages for the key.

However, we notice that the results get pushed early and not wait until the final. What could be the possible reasons

1. Is it based on commit.interval.ms value set to 1 sec and can push the results earlier that the punctuate schedule?
2. Do we need to use a global store to push the aggregate records based on key since we have 10 partitions and 10 consumer threads in total split between 2 application instances

Answer (score 0):

You might need to keep track of the last time Kafka Streams executed your `punctuate` method and ensure that it forwards records only after the acceptable amount of time has passed.